# Как решить проблему с файлом keystore?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, keystore

Всем привет. Мне дали приложение, сказали выкатить обновление, ну я сгенерировал файл с помощью предоставленного мне файлом, но установка не получилась, кто-нибудь может сталкивался с подобным?
[image: gradle]

[image: gradle]

[image: Ошибка]

Answer (score 0):

Выброси этот градл и подпиши руками:

```
jarsigner -verbose -keypass shit123 -storepass shit123 -keystore shit.key tmp.apk shit
```

В данном примере:

- `shit123` - это пароль для кейстора и самого ключа
- `shit.key` - сам кейстор (файлик)
- `tmp.apk` - то, что мы собрались подписывать
- `shit` - то, чем подписываем

Это все. Можно ставить на девайс. Если прогнать `zipalign`, то можно сразу в маркет заливать.

Comment: Спасибо большое, быстренько вопрос shit - то,чем подписываем - что указывать?

Comment: Алиас, как назван ключ

Comment: сейчас попробую

Comment: мне apk файл брать в котором ошибка была или как?

Comment: Который без подписи. Внутри которого нету директории META-INF. Раньше в эклипсе можно было просто создать файл без подписи, но это было в эпоху до градла.

Comment: а все, понял unsigned он называется еще

Comment: в общем выходит вот такая надпись only one alias can be specified. типа туда больше нельзя

Comment: @BulatGusmanov, в AS визард есть в меню Build для этого, там все пошагово и каждый шаг проверяется. Пройдите, хотя бы поймете где косяк.

Comment: @BulatGusmanov, а вам надо несколько?

Comment: @bukkojot странный совет про выбрасывание градла, который делает абсолютно то же, что вы и написали. он вызывает `jarsigner` и `zipalign`

Comment: @bukkojot, дело в том что у меня уже есть файл jks, данный проект делал не я, а прошлые разработчики, мне сейчас нужно обновление выкатить, так как я добавил туда функционал, я использую jks который дали прошлые разработчики, генерирую signed apk и получаю ошибку при установке

Comment: @DeKaNszn, чем занимаются jarsigner и zipalign я хотя бы знаю и понимаю, а чем занимается толстая неповоротливая прокладка со странным синтаксисом и вообще назначением - не очень.

Comment: @BulatGusmanov, я твою задачу понял и описал что делать. Вместо shit.key подставляешь свой кейстор, пишешь пароли, радуешься. Если у тебя что-то не получается, то изложи что именно, как именно не получается, снабди оп-пост описанием того что было сделано, может быть добавь логов или хотя бы скриншотов ошибок, так как что тебе нехватает, да и вообще, что ты хочешь от нас, имея готовое решение - мне совершенно не ясно.

Comment: @bukkojot gradle запускает сторонние утилиты, позволяя не устраивать чехарду из скриптов "этот запускает компиляцию", "этот запускает тесты", "этот проверяет codestyle", "этот собирает апк из классов", "этот подписывает апк". насчет неповоротливости - вы явно что-то перемудрили. может у вас до сих пор gradle < 4.1 ?. PS: gradle позволяет выкачать и собрать проект прямо из командной строки, что часто используется в CI

Comment: @bukkojot ясно, скриптами обходите момент с desugar java7 кода для апи менее 19? (про решение вопроса с java8 кодом нет смысла спрашивать)

Comment: А что, уже можно использовать седьмой JDK? Мне тут в 2012-м году без него нормально.